# Can't get tokens from Runabove API (Openstack swift)

Tags: python, openstack-swift, cloud-storage

I'm writing a python scripts which uses OpenStack and Runabove APIs. I want to generate a token from the Runabove API which will be used to connect to SwiftClient.

```
run = Runabove(app_key, app_secret, consumer_key)
token = run.tokens.get()
```

It comes from there: https://github.com/runabove/python-runabove/blob/master/examples/openstack/openstack.py (lines 82 -> 85)

This code raises:

```
raise BadParametersError(msg=json_result.get('message'))
runabove.exception.BadParametersError: Invalid signature
```

which means that a HTTPError 400 is raised:
https://github.com/runabove/python-runabove/blob/master/runabove/wrapper_api.py (line 164)

I have no clue where my problem can come from and I'm 100% sure that my keys/secret are correct.

Thanks

Comment: This might help :
https://github.com/runabove/python-runabove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure your application keys and secrets are valid, but you need a consumer key too !

You can read [runabove-python package readme](https://github.com/runabove/python-runabove) to understand how to create a consumer key, then you can add it to the example you provided and it will work perfectly.

You can also read this [KB](https://community.runabove.com/kb/en/instances/how-to-use-runabove-api.html) on RunAbove website to understand why you need this consumer key and how it can help you to filter requests with an ACL-like system.